# Using stack defined in C++ stl

Tags: c++, stl, stack

```
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack<int> s;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        s.push(i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", s.pop());
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with the code above?

**Error:**

> In function `int main()`: aggregate value used where an integer was expected

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`stack::pop`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) is a `void` function which just discards the top element on the stack, in order to get the value you want to use [`stack::top`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top).

The reason this is so is for [exception safety reasons](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/444) (what happens if the object returned throws an exception in its copy constructor?).

Comment: Ooh, never realized that was the reason. I always just thought it was a cleanliness of design/separation of concerns kind of thing. +1 for enlightening me. :)

Comment: Also, `pop` would have to create a copy in order to return it. If the user doesn't want that, it's probably going to end up costing performance.

Comment: According to Stroustrup (TC++PL), the actual reason was performance: if `pop` returned the value, it would have to create an unnecessary copy (since the value is consecutively destroyed in the stack). Both sound plausible though (and both are made obsolete by move semantics).

Comment: @Konrad, since move contructor's are [allowed to throw](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2983.html) I don't think you can have an exception safe `pop` that returns the value. Not to mention the question of thread safety.

Comment: But what about (N)RVO? Wouldn't `pop` just construct the top value directly, before "popping" it, so in case the exception happens - nothing will be lost. So no move constructors will be invoked anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Minor nitpick, your for loop is actually encoding 11 items and not 10 like you make think from a brief look at the loop count.  Consider using < 11 if you mean 11 elements to add.

Answer (score 1):

You're treating pop() which is an operation to print to standard output. pop()
just removes the topmost element from the stack. The most confusing thing however
is your debug output.

I compiled your code fragment with the standard GNU C++ compiler 
which gave me:

> main.cpp|12|error: invalid use of void expression

```
int main() {
    stack<int> s;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        s.push(i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
          printf("%i", s.top());
          s.pop();
    }
}
```