# Why is pop() void?

Tags: c++, stack

For stack `pop()` is void, which means I need two lines of code whenever I want to get the top and pop:

```
auto top = s.top();
s.pop();
```

It would be convenient if I could just do:

```
auto top = s.pop();
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: For exception safety.

Comment: @Jarod42: Do you mean to remind people that `std::stack` is *not* thread-safe?  Because the two-operation API is the worst for concurrency.

Comment: http://cpptruths.blogspot.fr/2005/10/why-does-stdstackpop-returns-void.html

Comment: @Jarod42 If thread safety was the issue, then `top()` shouldn't return a reference.

Comment: Sometimes you want to top without popping and sometimes you want to pop without topping so I suppose its probably more efficient not to combine them.

Comment: I think he meant exception safety.

Comment: Could be due to slightly improved complexity, returning the item just popped would require a move-assignment at the least.

Comment: if copy constructor throws, you would lose the element in container, without recovery possible.

Comment: @ben bought: non of the stl containers is thread safe. Reminding people about it is irrelevant.

Comment: Related to [can-a-stack-have-an-exception-safe-method-for-returning-and-removing-the-top-ele](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620357/can-a-stack-have-an-exception-safe-method-for-returning-and-removing-the-top-ele)